# How do I automate SFTP to get rid of the password prompt?

Tags: automation, sftp

I need to perform SFTP automation (to get rid of the password prompt). How can I do this?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a public/private key. [How can I automate an SFTP transfer between two servers?](http://ask-leo.com/how_can_i_automate_an_sftp_transfer_between_two_servers.html)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is using SSH authorized_keys. You will need to create a key on the client side (using ssh-keygen) and then copy the public key to the target side.

```
client-machine% ssh-keygen -t rsa
client-machine% scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@target-machine:~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Note that if you want to access target-machine from two or more "clients", you can not copy the id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys2 directly. You will need to open authorized_keys2 and paste the id_rsa.pub from each client machine on it (or use the line below to append the content)

```
client-machine% cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@target-machine \
                'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Now you can use ssh/scp without user/password information:

```
client-machine% ssh user@target-machine
client-machine% scp file user@target-machine:~/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the VisualCron automation suite. It has built in automation for SFTP and SSH as well as normal FTP. http://www.visualcron.com

Answer (score 0):

If security is not a concern then the password can be in
clear text in your script. E.g. on Microsoft Windows using
pscp from the [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) package.

Example:

```
"d:\putty0.58\pscp"  -pw MyNotSoSecretPassWord  u:\outGoing\someFileToTransfer.7z  kingOfTheHill@www.pil.sdu.dk:/srv/www/htdocs/1/MSQuantDynamics/someFileToTransfer.7z
```

Password: MyNotSoSecretPassWord. User name: kingOfTheHill. Host: www.pil.sdu.dk.

The sftp server in our case runs on a Linux based server.